# Problem traversing generic relationship with different types of primary keys

Tags: django-models, django-generic-relations

I have the following models (greatly simplified)

```
class Species(models.Model):
    # automatic primary key: id, bigint
    label = models.CharField(
        null=True, blank=True,
        max_length=LABEL_LENGTH
    ) 
    photos = GenericRelation(Photo, related_query_name='species')
     
class FieldNotes(models.Model)
    fulcrum_id = models.CharField(
        max_length = EXTERNAL_ID_LENGTH,
        primary_key=True
    )
    scan_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=LABEL_LENGTH,
    ) 
    photos = GenericRelation(Photo, related_query_name='species')

class Media(models.Model):
    # automatic primary key: id, bigint

    caption = models.TextField(
        blank=True, default='',
    )

    object_id = models.CharField(
        max_length = EXTERNAL_ID_LENGTH,
    )
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Photo(Media):
    photo= models.ImageField(
        upload_to ='photo/%Y/%m/',    
    )
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="photos")

class Video(Media):
    video = models.FileField(
        null=True, blank=True,
        upload_to='videos/', )
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
          related_name="videos")
```

This works generally fine, but when I want to query for example Species that have a photo with a certain caption

`qs = Species.objects.filter(photos__caption='abc')`

I get the following error:

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: bigint = character varying`

Obviously this comes from the mismatch between foreign key and primary key types, varchar vs bigint.

If I do the same query for model FieldNotes it works

`qs = FieldNotes.objects.filter(photos__caption='abc')`

Question: Django documentation (`https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/`) states that:

> Primary key type compatibility
>
> The “object_id” field doesn’t have to be the same type as the primary
> key fields on the related models, but their primary key values must be
> coercible to the same type as the “object_id” field by its
> get_db_prep_value() method.

So this should work, why doesn't it? Is there a way I make it work without changing the primary key type in FieldNotes (and other similar models)?

Comment: "should be coercible", a bigint is not coeercible with a varchar. This merely is that a `BigInteger` will work with an `Integer` and vice versa.

Comment: @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike:  Thank you,but not according to the Django documention, which states: 
The “object_id” field doesn’t have to be the same type as the primary key fields on the related models, but their primary key values must be coercible to the same type as the “object_id” field by its get_db_prep_value() method.

For example, if you want to allow generic relations to models with either IntegerField or CharField primary key fields, you can use CharField for the “object_id” field on your model since integers can be coerced to strings by get_db_prep_value().

Comment: Your own documentation part: "*but their primary key values must be coercible to the same type as the “object_id” field by its `get_db_prep_value()` method.*", so it works if both fields have a `get_db_prep_value()` that for example produce a `str`, or a `datetime`, or an `int` or something equivalent.

Comment: The object_id is a string, the primary keys are either strings or ints. ints can be coerced to strings. According to my reading of the docs this should work. Maybe the docs are just wrong?

Comment: you seem to think that this is about how the database coerces, but the "coerce" relation is defined in the next sentence: when `get_db_prep_value()` produces the same type, `str` and `int` are not the same type.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have misread the Django documentation you cite:

> Primary key type compatibility
>
> The “`object_id`” field doesn’t have to be the same type as the primary key fields on the related models, but **their primary key values must be coercible to the same type as the “`object_id`” field by its `get_db_prep_value()` method.**.

This thus means that for example an `IntegerField` and a `BigIntegerField` because the `get_db_prep_value()`, the value that Django uses to convert a value to a parameter in an SQL query, will produce for both an `int`. This will not work for a `CharField` and an `IntegerField` (which is essentially the problem here): a `CharField` produces a `str` for the `get_db_prep_value()` whereas an `IntegerField` produces an `int`, hence the two do *not* coerce.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a limitation of Django's generic relationships.

Queries like

```
qs = FieldNotes.objects.filter(photos__caption__icontains='abc')
```

work, but only if the types of foreign keys and primary keys match

However:

`one_species.photos.count()`  etc

*work even if the primary key in Species is an integer. This is because the type-mismatch, even without explicit coercion, is resolved by the SQL engine:

```
>>> from scans.models.fieldnotes_species import FieldNotes_Species 
    as Species
>>> one_species = Species.objects_for_count.get(id=6720)
>>> qs1 = one_species.photos.all()
>>> print(qs1.query)
SELECT "core_photo"."id", "core_photo"."external_id", 
...
"core_photo"."signature_timestamp", "core_photo"."content_type_id" 
FROM "core_photo" WHERE ("core_photo"."content_type_id" = 137 
AND "core_photo"."object_id" = 6720)
>>> qs1.count()
3
>>>
```

However, in the context of doing a filter on a to-many relationship, this will result in a join, and for the join condition the type-mismatch is not tolerated by the SQL engine.

```
>>> qs = Species.objects.filter(photos__caption__icontains='a')
>>> print(qs.query)
SELECT "scans_fieldnotes_species"."id",
 ...
"scans_fieldnotes_species"."cover_class_braun_blanquet_id" 
 FROM "scans_fieldnotes_species" INNER JOIN "core_photo" 
ON ("scans_fieldnotes_species"."id" = "core_photo"."object_id" 
AND ("core_photo"."content_type_id" = 137)) 
WHERE UPPER("core_photo"."caption"::text) LIKE UPPER(%a%)
```

I think that is something that could be clearer in the documentation, if that is a known limitation.